# Why does getCoordinates return long coordinates?

Tags: openlayers

After click on the map I got long coordinates values as:

```
[5364981.75481758, 7224346.2294111]
```

Code line is:

```
  const geom = (
    this.editFeaturePointClone.getGeometry() as any
  ).getCoordinates();
```

So, I need to pass these coordinates to any map (Google as example) to view the object. But I got the wrong coordinates.

How to fix it?

I have tried this:

```
 const [lon, lat] = evt.coordinate;
        const coordReprojected = Proj.transform(
          [lon, lat],
          'EPSG:4326',
          'EPSG:3857'
        );

        (
          this.drawingService.editFeaturePoint.getGeometry() as any
        ).setCoordinates(coordReprojected);
```

Comment: You need to reproject them, there are many answers on how to do that

Comment: Could you explain how to do it into worlds coordinates?

Comment: To get Lon Lat coordinates of drawn features use `feature.getGeometry().clone().transform(map.getView().getProjection(), 'EPSG:4326').getCoordinates()`

Comment: Ot works, but I got the coordinates that refers to another object on the map